# Match till comma OR end of line

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
0               UDP/ax/bsd
1     T Traffic/sa
2     ICMP/v/e,stuff hi/a/abc,ab/a
```

I want to replace everything from the first encountered `/` till a comma or end of line. So I tried initially `df.col_A.replace('/.+','',regex=True)` which just gave me the first word (till first slash).

To get comma separated words I attempted the following:

```
`df.col_A.replace('/.+[,$]',',',regex=True)`
```

My logic being replace everything from slash till [comma or EOL]. This didn't have the expected behaviour. How do I amend this?

The expected ouput from line 2(3) of the data frame is:

```
ICMP,stuff hi, ab
```

Note that I am trying to avoid using split as I think this may take longer since it stores the irrelevant pieces as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can  use:

```
 >>> print re.sub(r'/[^,]*(,|$)', ' \1', 'ICMP/v/e,stuff hi/a/abc,ab/a')
ICMP stuff hi ab
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gV7gI6/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
/       # match literal /
[^,]*   # match 0 or more of any character that is not comma
(,|$)   # Match comma or end of line and capture it as group #1
```

Replacement is `" \1"` which means space followed by back-reference to group #1

Comment: I think, replace with ', ' only if end matches with ','?

Comment: Since I'm fairly new to regex could you add an explanation as to what the symbols mean?

Comment: I've added detailed explanation of regex used. Also visit this useful site for learning regex: http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: A problem here is that it won't stop matching the end of line if there are multiple lines, see https://regex101.com/r/qhsgdp/2

Comment: @Marki: If you are using multiple strings with line breaks then use `/[^,\n]*(,|$)`

Comment: @anubhava Yeah that helps. \n and $ are not the same. You nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

The construction `[....]` matches a set of characters. In this context `$` is a character. You should use the pipe (`|`) if you want to match alternative regular expressions (where `$` is a regular expression). I also prefer to use `\Z` instead of `$` and since the normal `+` operator eat as much as possible, you need to use `+?` get the shortest extent and not eat the entire line.

```
df.col_A.replace('/.+?(,|$)','',regex=True)
```

However, since the `+` operator try matches as much as possible, you can get away with this:

```
df.col_A.replace('/[^,]+','',regex=True)
```

Where `[^,]+` means "as many characters as possible that is not a comma."

Comment: your second regex worked but the first didn't. Also I used `replace` instead of `sub`. When I used sub I get the error: `flex_wrapper() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'`